# ng-repeat breaking directive model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input-directive model="config.shared.product.whatevers[0]"></input-directive> 

<!-- above works, below doesn't bind properly -->

<td ng-repeat="whatever in config.shared.product.whatevers track by $index">
   <input-directive model="whatever"></input-directive>
</td>
```

Basically the model doesn't update from this fully working directive when it is inside an ng-repeat. It can read the value but doesn't update when I change the value of the input. Let me know if you need more code!

Comment: 1.  is your directive's property `model` 2-way bound (`=`)?, 2. what is an example of `whatever`?  can you try having it be an object?

Comment: Yeah they're two way bound. Model is a reference to a variable on an object. It's just a number in this case.

Comment: Can you see what happens if you make `whatevers[n]` all objects, and pass `whatever.value` or something into the directive?

Comment: What do you mean 'all objects'?

Comment: a javascript object.  like `var x = {"value": "test"}` is an object and `x.value` references that.

Comment: oh right I misunderstood. whatevers is an array of values: whatevers[2] = 9 for example

Comment: What I'm saying is that Javascript treats literals like ints differently from Objects for the purposes of inheritance.  Without seeing more, it's possible that your problem comes from using ints instead of Objects.  Which is why I'm suggesting you try manually creating a list of Objects to take the place of `whatevers` and test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this. I was using primitives.

My object:
    `{ bananas: [1,2,3,4,5] }`

However, to use this in an ng-repeat do:
    `{ bananas: [ { value:1 }, { value:2 }... ] }` and reference the value. I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this though.